# Difference between an, ab aus and ein (schrauben, schalten, etc)

Tags: verb, prefix

The mixed usage of these prefixes confuses me.

For example, I tipically hear *einschrauben* to mean the opposite of *abschrauben* (say when screwin/unscrewing a nut). However the true opposite should be *anschrauben* I believe.

Another example where I hear a not exact pairing of opposites is with the verb *schalten* (say in switching a light switch). It seems (from my limited empirical experience) *einschalten* and *anschalten* are synonyms (and so are *aus*- and *abschalten*) and I can mix and match them.

What is the difference between the usage of *ein*- and *an*- prefixes? And *aus*- and *ab*-? When can they be used interchangeably?

Are the following sentences correct?

> Du musst die Mutter abschrauben und dann wieder einschrauben.
>   Du musst das Licht abschalten und dann wieder einschalten.

Comment: You wrote that you typically here _einschrauben_ - can you name/guess the German dialect that is spoken a) in the area you live and/or b) in the area the speaking person(s) come from?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Frankfurt region, native germans. The exact dialect I do not know, but I can tell they pronouce "nit" instead of nicht (i.e. Weiß ich "nit").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked: Is this correct?

> Du musst die Mutter abschrauben und dann wieder einschrauben.

This is not really wrong, but this one is better:

> Du musst die Mutter abschrauben und dann wieder **anschrauben.**

Second sentence:

> Du musst das Licht abschalten und dann wieder einschalten.

Again: not wrong, and maybe in some regions even the preferred version, but it could be done better (turning of the lights is not a really complicated process):

> Du musst das Licht **ausschalten** und dann wieder einschalten.

---

### schrauben

- **einschrauben**
  If you have something to screw into a hole, like screwing a light bulb into its holder, or screwing in a screw into a thread, then it is **einschrauben**:

  > Ich werde eine neue Glühbirne **einschrauben.**
  >   <sup>I will screw in a new light bulb.</sup>
  >
  > Ich muss nur noch diese Gehäuseschraube **einschrauben**, dann bin ich mit der Reparatur deines Computers fertig.
  >   <sup>All I have to do is screw this housing screw in, then I'm done with the repair of your computer.</sup>
- **hineinschrauben**
  If you have to screw a screw into wood or a similar material where no thread exists before, then *einschrauben* is possible too, but **hineinschrauben** is a better choice:

  > Ich werde hier noch eine Schraube in den Balken **hineinschrauben**, dann kannst du das Bild daran aufhängen.
  >   <sup>I'll screw another screw into the beam here, then you can hang the picture on it.</sup>
- **anschrauben**
  This verb is used if you want tu attach one thing onto another thing using screws:

  > Der Hausmeister muss noch das Schild an der Tür **anschrauben.**
  >   <sup>The janitor still has to attach the sign on the door with screws.</sup>

  But it also can mean to screw something that has a thread onto something else:

  > Ich werde hier einen Wasserhahn an das Rohr **anschrauben.**
  >   <sup>I'll screw a faucet to the pipe here.</sup>
- **abschrauben**
  When a jar has a screw top, and you want to open this jar (i.e. remove the screw top), then you use **abschrauben**. But you also use this verb when you remove something, that was attached with skrews:

  > Kannst du bitte den Deckel vom Marmeladeglas **abschrauben**?
  >   <sup>Can you please unscrew the lid from the jam jar?</sup>
  >
  > Ich werde das Türschild **abschrauben.**
  >   <sup>I will unscrew the door plate.</sup>
- **ausschrauben, herausschrauben**
  This is the opposite of *einschrauben, hineinschrauben*

  > Vorher musst du die alte Glühbirne **herausschrauben.**
  >   First you have to unscrew the old light bulb.

I found 21 verbs deriving from *schrauben*. I think it would be too much to explain all of them. Here is just the list in alphabetical order:

> abschrauben, anschrauben, aufschrauben, auseinanderschrauben, ausschrauben, einschrauben, emporschrauben, festschrauben, heraufschrauben, herausschrauben, herumschrauben, herunterschrauben, hinaufschrauben, hochschrauben, höherschrauben, losschrauben, runterschrauben, verschrauben, zurückschrauben, zusammenschrauben, zuschrauben

---

### schalten

- **anschalten**
  This means to turn on a device.

  > Kannst du bitte den Geschirrspüler **anschalten**?
  >   <sup>Please can you turn on the dishwasher?</sup>
  >
  > Ich werde jetzt den Fernseher **anschalten**.
  >   <sup>I will turn on the TV.</sup>
- **einschalten**
  This can be a synonym of *anschalten*:

  > Kannst du bitte den Geschirrspüler **einschalten**?
  >   <sup>Please can you turn on the dishwasher?</sup>

  But is also can mean to hand over a case to the police or a layer. (This is not possible with *anschalten*):

  > Wenn Sie mir drohen, werde ich meinen Anwalt **einschalten.**
  >   <sup>If you threaten me, I will hand it over to my lawyer.</sup>
- **ausschalten**
  This is the opposite of *anschalten* and *einschalten* (not meaning the layer):

  > Wenn du gehst, musst du das Licht **ausschalten.**
  >   <sup>When you leave, you have to turn off the lights.</sup>
- **abschalten**
  Technically this is a synonym of *ausschalten*, but more often you use *abschalten* only if turning off is a long and complicated process.

  > 50.000 Demonstranten forderten, das alte Atomkraftwerk endlich **ab**zu**schalten.**
  >   <sup>50,000 demonstrators called for the old nuclear power plant to be shut down at last.</sup>

29 Verbs derived from *schalten*:

> abschalten, anschalten, aufschalten, ausschalten, beschalten, dazwischenschalten, durchschalten, einschalten, freischalten, gleichschalten, heraufschalten, herschalten, herunterschalten, hintereinanderschalten, hinunterschalten, hochschalten, nachschalten, parallelschalten, raufschalten, runterschalten, umschalten, verschalten, vorschalten, wegschalten, weiterschalten, zurückschalten, zusammenschalten, zuschalten, zwischenschalten

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you mentioned I would consider all uses correct, although in the case of "Mutter" I would prefer "anschrauben". The word "einschrauben" would fit better for a screw, where "ein" as a short form of "hinein" would mean "into". The "aus" in "ausschrauben" would be a short form of "heraus". It would not be "an" and "aus" in the sense "on" and "off".

For a nut or "Mutter" the word "anschrauben" wold fit better because the nut gets outside the screw.

Preferences would vary in indifferent regions.
For light I would use "an-" or "ein-" for on and "aus-" or "ab-" for off.
For a nut I would use "an-" and "ab-".
For a screw I would use "(hin)ein-" and "(her)aus-".